# TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

it say TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression and whene i delete await it not work

> ```
> @bot.event
> async def on_message_delete(message):
>      snipe_message_author[message.channel.id] = message.author
>      snipe_message_content[message.channel.id] = message.content
>      await time.sleep(2) # <=== here 
>      del snipe_message_author[message.channel.id]
>      del snipe_message_content[message.channel.id]
> ```

Comment: In so many words `time.sleep()` runs there and then, and returns `None` to `await`. The mechanism for "sleeping" in async code looks quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `time.sleep()`, you need to use `asyncio.sleep()`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message): 
     snipe_message_author[message.channel.id] = message.author
     snipe_message_content[message.channel.id] = message.content
     await asyncio.sleep(2)
     del snipe_message_author[message.channel.id]
     del snipe_message_content[message.channel.id]
```

You also need to import asyncio by placing `import asyncio` at the top of your code. You can also use `from asyncio import sleep` and use `sleep()` instead of `asyncio.sleep()` but this is not recommended as you might have another `sleep()` function.